# number of comparisons needed to sort n values?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am working on revised selection sort algorithm so that on each pass it finds both the largest and smallest values in the *unsorted portion of the array*. The sort then moves each of these values into its correct location by swapping array entries.

My question is - **How many comparisons are necessary to sort n values?**

In normal selection sort it is O(n) comparisons so I am not sure what will be in this case?

Comment: No it does not take `O(n)` comparisons in normal [selection sort](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/Algorithms/Lessons/WorstCaseSelectionSort/index.html)

Comment: It is impossible to do comparison sorting using less than `O(n log n)` comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal selection sort requires `O(n^2)` comparisons.

At every run it makes K comparisons where K is `n-1, n-2, n-3...1`, and sum of this arithmetic progression is `(n*(n-1)/2)`

Your approach (if you are using optimized min/max choice scheme) use `3/2*K` comparisons per run, where run length K is `n, n-2, n-4...1`

Sum of arithmetic progression with a(1)=1, a(n/2)=n, d=2 together with 3/2 multiplier is

```
 3/2 * 1/2 * (n+1) * n/2 = 3/8 * n*(n+1) = O(n^2)
```

So complexity remains quadratic (and factor is very close to standard)

Answer (score 0):

In your version of selection sort, first you would have to choose two elements as the `minimum` and `maximum`, and all of the remaining elements in the unsorted array can get compared with both of them in the worst case.
Let's say if `k` elements are remaining in the unsorted array, and assuming you pick up first two elements and accordingly assign them to `minimum` and `maximum` (1 comparison), then iterate over the rest of `k-2` elements, each of which can result in 2 comparisons.
So, total comparisons for this iteration will be `= 1 + 2*(k-2) = 2*k - 3` comparisons.
Here `k` will take values as `n, n-2, n-4, ...` since in every iteration two elements get into their correct position. The summation will result in approximately `O(n^2)` comparisons.